# Wordpress: Custom post type single page shows index page instead

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've have tried to make my first wordpress theme and I have some trouble with my single pages for my blog.
[my blog page][1]

It is a custom post type, that I created called blog_post.
The weird this seems to happen only when it is on a sublayer of my site ex. {url}/blog_post/ here the page looks just like my index page.

But on my work page there isn't any problem with my single pages, and their permalink doesn't have a {url}/work_post/ attach to them.
[my work page][2]

I created the special styling of my single pages with functions.php file

```
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH . '/single');

/**
* Filter the single_template with our custom function
*/
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

/**
* Single template function which will choose our template
*/
function my_single_template($single) {
global $wp_query, $post;

/**
* Checks for single template by category
* Check by category slug and ID
*/
foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :

if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';
/*                                                                                                                              <-------- if no single-cat page is found the return the single.php file 
*/
elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php'))
return SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php';

endforeach;
}
```

**I hope someone can make sense of my mess :D**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself by simply removing the additions to functions.php and then making custom post for my work page as well.

then I make single-{slug}.php pages for every slug I wanted :D
everybody is happy

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "public => true" in your custom post type. Also create single-{custom-post-type}.php file

Code:

```
$args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'heirachical'       => false,
        'menu_position'     => 26,
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-products',
        'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail' ),
        'query_var'         => true,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'rewrite'           => true,
    );
```

For example: Suppose you have created custom post type say "product" then you need to create single-product.php file in your theme directory.

Note: Save your permalink setting.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to add `'publicly_queryable' => true` to the arguments of registering the post_type. I originally had to setting set to `false`.